# Filtering inherited objects

Tags: django, django-models

I have a base class A . Two derived classes B , C.
Now I have a global class witch contains a many-to-many relation to object A.

```
Class D:
    aObjects : ManyToMany("A")
```

how could know the real object the filter query return in object D.
I mean : `d.objects.get(id=5)`
now d has n objects of class A, but they are a mix of A,B or C.
How can get only those of type B in the query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this automatically. The documentation is quite clear that there's no way to tell from an instance of a base class whether or not it should 'actually' be an instance of a derived class.

The only thing to do is to define a field on the base class that shows what derived type it is, and set this automatically in the the `save()` method of the various derived classes. Then you can filter on the value of this field.

Answer (score 0):

Will this works for you

`filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, B), d.objects.get(id=5))`